# Auto-select Radio Button with Text Field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

Did lots of searching on here and found plenty of people with similar questions, but every 'solution' I have found fails to work in my case. I could be missing something simple, or it may have to do with our HTML. Basically, I want our text field to check it's corresponding radio button should someone enter a value there.

Here is a JSFiddle with what I want working, but when I put host it on a server for testing I don't get the same result.

**JSFiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/p8kvQ/39/

**HTML**

```
<div>
  <input type="radio" name="UnitPrice1" id="UnitPrice1" value="47" checked="checked" />
  <label for="UnitPrice1">$47</label>
</div>

<div>
  <input type="radio" name="UnitPrice1" id="UnitPrice2" value="Other" />
  <label for="UnitPrice2">Other</label>
  <input class="-input-width-auto" name="Other1" type="number" id="Other1" />
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('#Other1').click(function(){
  $('#UnitPrice2').trigger('click');
});
```

I DO have "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js" defined in our HTML header and I've tried adding the code by defining its source file, but still no luck.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Any chance you can give us the url to your actual application?

Comment: Which browser are you testing this in?

Comment: Ensure your final output really renders the IDs you think it should. Check for JS errors occurring before the line that assigns the event handler (watch your developer console carefully).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your JS needs to be inside a `document.ready`. When the code is run, the dom element is not available, there for your click listener can not be attached it it.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('#Other1').click(function(){ 
    $('#UnitPrice2').trigger('click');
  });
});
```

(JSFiddle does this for you because you have the following setting: http://screencast.com/t/5WUC33diHpTb)

Comment: Ah! Thanks so much. I figured it had something to do with that OnLoad function but I wasn't sure what I was missing. This solved it.

Comment: Sorry about that! I gave you acceptance. Thanks again!